# Get material linked document data

Tags: sap-erp, function-module

I want to get data from SAP ERP and put new data (material and document) to SAP ERP. I'm using the ERPConnect .Net tool from theobald software. But the question is not ERPConnect specific, any solution in C++, C# or any other language are fine. The SAP ERP is not running in our company it's for a customer who use our CAD software.

Actually the function module `CO_DM_MAT_GET_DOC_LINKS` does exactly what I want. Returns all linked docs. Unfortunately this module can't be called via remote.

Anybody know how I can receive material master linked document info records, using function modules?

Thanks in advance
Thomas

Comment: hi, i hope by using **Select** statement itself u can retrieve the material master linked document info records

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following RFCs:

- BAPI_MATERIAL_GETLIST
- BAPI_MATERIAL_GET_DETAIL
- BAPI_DOCUMENT_GETOBJECTDOCS
- BAPI_DOCUMENT_GETOBJECTLINKS
- BAPI_DOCUMENT_GETDETAIL
- BAPI_DOCUMENT_GETDETAIL2

You may have to mix and match a bit to get all the data that you need.

Comment: I have not watch this for a long time thanks for looking at this. I'm using a tool, called ERPConnect. I get the linked docs via BAPI_DOCUMENT_GETOBJECTDOCS.